# add product quantity based on store

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I have created two stores(**store1** and **store2**) in Magento. I have **productA** 100 quantities for **store1** and 50 quantities for **store2**. How can I manage this using single product(single **sku**).

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, Magento does not have the ability to manage separate inventory across multiple stores or websites.

You have 2 options:

1. Create 2 different products (one for each store like you mentioned)
2. Look into buying a multi-website inventory extension like https://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_multi_location_inventory.html

Note: To use this extension you would have to configure your installation as 2 websites instead of 2 stores